# Where should I ask a question related to the reversal of a computer algorithm based on a mathematical function?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**Edit:** *I've actually just figured out the answer to the question I was going to ask, so I no longer require any assistance finding a site to ask it on. I am very thankful for the suggestions I received in the comments, however, as I will now have a better idea of where to go if I have a similar question in the future.*

I have recently written a computer algorithm which, at its core, is driven by a well established mathematical function (The Cantor pairing function). I am struggling to develop a functional reversal of my algorithm, and I've come to realize that I do not posses the mathematical or reverse engineering knowledge necessary to solve my problem. This had lead me to seek help on one of the stack exchange sites.

My question involves code, math, and the reverse engineering of an algorithm, which seems to point me in the direction of either [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site, but I'm truly not sure where I should go. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need,an algorithm for an appropriate numerical method, I would suggest 'not SO'.  Sounds like it should be on-topic for Mathematics, but check the rules/policy first:).  If you then have problems implementing it, try SO:)

Comment: Yes, Mathematics.se makes sense. Inverting the function is discussed at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function so you may want to start by saying that you know of that page.

Comment: [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be another option. Could you add your actual question into this question, so that we can help you better?

Comment: Also note that in a CompSci context 'reverse engineering' may not mean what you think it means. There are two quite separate meanings to 'the reverse engineering of an algorythm' in the context of your question and I'm not sure which one you mean.

Comment: @Glorfindel I just wrote and added my actual question to this question as you suggested - After doing this, I've come to realize that my question is far more code related than it is math related.

Comment: @simonatrcl You're likely correct. I'm attempting to reverse and algorithm that I wrote, which doesn't exactly fit the definition of "reverse engineering." I was just trying to find a term that would help me articulate what I needed help with.